# No Mouse / Keyboard since Upgrade to 20.04 in VPS Server with standard Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: xorg, 20.04

When using the standard desktop I'm getting no mouse, keyboard with Ubuntu 20.04 on a VPServer.

I'm able to show the Desktop in VNC but without mouse / keyboard it is pretty much useless.

There are no errors but I think the last lines are the problem.

With Ubuntu 18.04 it worked without problems.

Any ideas?

I tried to remove / install
xserver-xorg-input-mouse
xserver-xrog-input-kbd

Furthermore I installed:
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04

That helped to fix graphic problems but not the mouse keyboard.

I tried to post the full log but it is blocked "this looks like spam"

```
    20.486] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    20.486] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    20.486] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    20.487] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[    20.487] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    20.487] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    20.488] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/event3)
[    20.488] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    20.488] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    20.496] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    20.496] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    20.496] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    20.497] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/event2)
[    20.497] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    20.497] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    20.498] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    20.498] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    20.498] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

[Xorg log output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMpcb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev solved the problem

Installing xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04 seems to be not necessary.

```
 76551.603] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[ 76551.603] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[ 76551.603] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[ 76551.603] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[ 76551.604] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 76551.604]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.10.6
[ 76551.604]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[ 76551.604]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[ 76551.604] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[ 76551.611] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 20 paused 0
[ 76551.611] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 76551.611] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[ 76551.612] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[ 76551.612] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[ 76551.612] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[ 76551.612] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0/event0"
[ 76551.612] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[ 76551.612] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[ 76551.612] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 76551.612] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 76551.614] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[ 76551.614] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[ 76551.614] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[ 76551.615] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 21 paused 0
[ 76551.615] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[ 76551.615] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[ 76551.615] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[ 76551.616] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[ 76551.616] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[ 76551.616] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input1/event1"
[ 76551.616] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[ 76551.616] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[ 76551.616] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 76551.616] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 76551.617] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/event3)
[ 76551.617] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 76551.617] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse'
[ 76551.619] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 22 paused 0
[ 76551.619] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: always reports core events
[ 76551.619] (**) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[ 76551.619] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x13
[ 76551.619] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[ 76551.619] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[ 76551.619] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Found relative axes
[ 76551.619] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Found x and y relative axes
[ 76551.619] (II) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Configuring as mouse
[ 76551.619] (II) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[ 76551.619] (**) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[ 76551.619] (**) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[ 76551.619] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3/event3"
[ 76551.619] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[ 76551.619] (II) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: initialized for relative axes.
[ 76551.619] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 76551.619] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[ 76551.619] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 76551.619] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 76551.620] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
[ 76551.620] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 76551.620] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 76551.621] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/event2)
[ 76551.621] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 76551.621] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse'
[ 76551.622] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 23 paused 0
[ 76551.622] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: always reports core events
[ 76551.622] (**) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[ 76551.622] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x13
[ 76551.622] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[ 76551.623] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Found absolute axes
[ 76551.623] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Found x and y absolute axes
[ 76551.623] (--) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Found absolute touchscreen
[ 76551.623] (II) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Configuring as touchscreen
[ 76551.623] (**) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[ 76551.623] (**) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[ 76551.623] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4/event2"
[ 76551.623] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 9)
[ 76551.623] (II) evdev: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: initialized for absolute axes.
[ 76551.623] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 76551.623] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[ 76551.623] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 76551.623] (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 76551.624] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 76551.624] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 76551.624] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```